# How to request data in react native swagger

Tags: javascript, react-native, swagger

I'm using [swagger-react-native-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-react-native-client) and trying to request data from [petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/?displayOperationId=false)

I Followed the tutorial and did this

```
Swagger('https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json')
  .then((client) => {
    console.log(client);
    console.log('---client---');

    client.apis.pet
      .findByStatus({status: 'available'})
      // client
      //   .execute({
      //     operationId: 'findByStatus',
      //     parameters: {status: 'available'},
      //   })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('---result---');
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('---error----');
        console.log(err.message);
        throw err;
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('---error----');
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
  });
```

and I'm getting the error

```
 client.apis.pet.findByStatus is not a function. (In 'client.apis.pet.findByStatus({
            status: 'available'
          })', 'client.apis.pet.findByStatus' is undefined)
[Fri Sep 04 2020 12:33:27.700]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: client.apis.pet.findByStatus is not a function. (In 'client.apis.pet.findByStatus({
            status: 'available'
          })', 'client.apis.pet.findByStatus' is undefined)
```

Since, there is no tutorial available online. I just tried some code and it's not working.

If my code is wrong or if I'm missing something kindly correct me.
How to request data from [petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/?displayOperationId=false) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I think you are looking for the function `findPetsByStatus` instead of `findByStatus`:

```
Swagger('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json').then((client) => {
  client.apis.pet.findPetsByStatus({status: 'available'}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

---

#### How I found the correct function name

I agree that it's kind of confusing because the swagger api does list a
GET request `/pet​/findByStatus` and the function name doesn't correspond with this.

I found the correct function name by logging the response from `Swagger(...)`, called `client` in your example, and looking through the properties and values this object has:

```
Swagger('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json').then((client) => {
  console.log(client) 
});
```

---

#### Explanation about Promises relating to your question

In the documentation we can read that Calling `Swagger(url, options)` returns a `Promise` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-react-native-client#constructor-and-methods).

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

So this means that in the `then` clause we have access to the resulting value of the (successful) asynchronous operation that is the `Swagger(...)` call. You've called this result `client` in your example.

This result is an object that holds a lot of different data, but importantly for your question; it has a property called `apis` which has an object as a value. This object contains all the api related functions you can use.

#### Representation of object returned from Swagger Promise

Here is a highly formatted and slightly adjusted (Adding quotes to `[Object]` and `[Function anonymous]` instances) representation of what you get when you log `client` in your example:

```
{
  "apis": {
    "pet": {
      "addPet": "[Function anonymous]",
      "deletePet": "[Function anonymous]",
      "findPetsByStatus": "[Function anonymous]",
      "findPetsByTags": "[Function anonymous]",
      "getPetById": "[Function anonymous]",
      "updatePet": "[Function anonymous]",
      "updatePetWithForm": "[Function anonymous]",
      "uploadFile": "[Function anonymous]"
    },
    "store": {
      "deleteOrder": "[Function anonymous]",
      "getInventory": "[Function anonymous]",
      "getOrderById": "[Function anonymous]",
      "placeOrder": "[Function anonymous]"
    },
    "user": {
      "createUser": "[Function anonymous]",
      "createUsersWithArrayInput": "[Function anonymous]",
      "createUsersWithListInput": "[Function anonymous]",
      "deleteUser": "[Function anonymous]",
      "getUserByName": "[Function anonymous]",
      "loginUser": "[Function anonymous]",
      "logoutUser": "[Function anonymous]",
      "updateUser": "[Function anonymous]"
    }
  },
  "errors": [],
  "originalSpec": "undefined",
  "spec": {
    "$$normalized": true,
    "basePath": "/v2",
    "definitions": {
      "ApiResponse": "[Object]",
      "Category": "[Object]",
      "Order": "[Object]",
      "Pet": "[Object]",
      "Tag": "[Object]",
      "User": "[Object]"
    },
    "externalDocs": {
      "description": "Find out more about Swagger",
      "url": "http://swagger.io"
    },
    "host": "petstore.swagger.io",
    "info": {
      "contact": "[Object]",
      "description": "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.",
      "license": "[Object]",
      "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
      "title": "Swagger Petstore",
      "version": "1.0.5"
    },
    "paths": {
      "/pet": "[Object]",
      "/pet/findByStatus": "[Object]",
      "/pet/findByTags": "[Object]",
      "/pet/{petId}": "[Object]",
      "/pet/{petId}/uploadImage": "[Object]",
      "/store/inventory": "[Object]",
      "/store/order": "[Object]",
      "/store/order/{orderId}": "[Object]",
      "/user": "[Object]",
      "/user/createWithArray": "[Object]",
      "/user/createWithList": "[Object]",
      "/user/login": "[Object]",
      "/user/logout": "[Object]",
      "/user/{username}": "[Object]"
    },
    "schemes": [
      "https",
      "http"
    ],
    "securityDefinitions": {
      "api_key": "[Object]",
      "petstore_auth": "[Object]"
    },
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "tags": [
      "[Object]",
      "[Object]",
      "[Object]"
    ]
  },
  "url": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"
}
```

Comment: Can you just show some lines of code on how client object looks and how you find it. Anyhow, I got the answer and I marked it as answer. But, It took some time for me to solve the problem based on your answer.

Comment: @rock I've updated my answer and added more explanation.

Comment: I have checked. That's great .